# Weird behavior - Class#getDeclaredMethods vs getMethods

Tags: java, reflection

I am aware of the fact that, `Class#getDeclaredMethods` returns declared methods of the class and `Class#getMethods` in additional contains the inherited methods. In short:

```
getDeclaredMethods is subset of getMethods
```

But how is the below output justified?

```
class A implements Comparator<Integer> {    
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return -1;
    }    
    private Object baz = "Hello";    
    private class Bar {
        private Bar() {
            System.out.println(baz);
        }
    }       
    Bar b = new Bar();    
}


for (Method m : claz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName()+ " " + m.isSynthetic());
}
```

It prints:

```
access$1 synthetic(true)
compare synthetic(false)
compare synthetic(true)
```

For the below:

```
for (Method m : claz.getMethods()) {
    System.out.println(m.getName() + " synthetic(" + m.isSynthetic()+")" );
}
```

It prints:

```
compare synthetic(false)
compare synthetic(true)
...//removed others for brievity
```

When we try printing methods of `A.class`, apart from visible methods it contains 2 additional synthetic methods `compare(Object, Object)` (bridge method) and `access$1` (for `Bar` to access elements of outer class `Foo`).

Both get printed in `declaredMethods`. But why doesn't `getMethods` print `access$1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`access$1` is not public - you can verify it by printing `Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers())`.

`getMethods()` [only shows public methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29):

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the ***public*** member methods of the class [...]

Comment: This is also the reason why the statement "*getDeclaredMethods is subset of getMethods*" is **NOT** true in general. One can only say that the intersection of the set of methods returned by both methods are the public methods that are declared directly in the respective class.